# Is It Possible To Find Shortened URL Versions of a Long URL?

Tags: url-shorteners

I'm wondering if I have a URL like: www.watermintstudios.com and I want to know if anyone else has made use of a bit.ly, goo.gl or other such URL shortening service to point to that URL is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 3):

Because URL shortening services obfuscate the destination URL, you would either need to be able to query their shortened URL to full URL records (which will probably not be supported by every service) or spider all of the obfuscated URLs to determine the destination URL (and compare against the URL you are looking for).

Of the services you mentioned, [bit.ly](http://dev.bitly.com/public_data.html) offers information about publicly-available URLs through its API, as does [goo.gl](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#url_analytics) - given that there are a variety of URL shortening solutions (including standalone scripts which webmasters can host on their sites) your mileage with other URL shortening services will vary, so building a comprehensive list of *all* shortened versions of a URL would not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.ttwi.st which is a premium URL shortener made for Internet Marketers. They are Clickbank friendly, have great tracking and have their own API. Your stats are also your own rather than shared with other people like some other URL shorteners.